# Give break and restart setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this car making tours with breaks. I want this below:

1) It should drive to the right side of the page

2) when it reaches 750 position left, it must stop.

3) pause 5 seconds

4) after pause, it must position itself to the left side of the page.

5) and start driving again.

**http://jsfiddle.net/mjTgB/6/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var showcar;
    showcar = setInterval(function () {
        var difference = $(".car").position().left
        if (difference < 750)
        {
            $('.car').css("left", "+=2px");
        }
        else
        {
            clearInterval(showcar);
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                $('.car').css("left", "-=700px");
                //want to re-start the interval
            },5000);
        }
    }, 10);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick solution is to drop the *existing* `.ready()` function in a variable for re-execution at the end of the run.

Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var run = function () {
    var showcar;
    showcar = setInterval(function () {
        var difference = $(".car").position().left
        if (difference < 750)
        {
            $('.car').css("left", "+=2px");
        }
        else
        {
            clearInterval(showcar);
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                $('.car').css("left", "-=700px");
                run();
            },5000);
        }
    }, 10);
  }
  run();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WGJ9g/1/

Answer (score 3):

```
var showcar;
STARTZOOM();
function STARTZOOM() {
    showcar = setInterval(CARZOOM, 10);
}
function CARZOOM() {
    var difference = $(".car").position().left
    if (difference < 750) {
        $('.car').css("left", "+=2px");
    } else {
        clearInterval(showcar);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.car').css("left", "-=700px");
            STARTZOOM();
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

like I mentioned in the chat, you need to just restart the interval the same way you originally called it, but instead of an anon function use a named function. I have put the 'restart' into its own function to reduce the code duplication. Note: my function names are intentionally bad.

Comment: [my code as written works perfectly fine](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/mjTgB/11/). Your issue is that you have not adapted it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should seperate your handler from your interval, so you can re-use it.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mjTgB/10/**

```
var showcar, interval;

showcar = function () {
    var difference = $(".car").position().left;

    if (difference < 750) {
        $('.car').css("left", "+=2px");
    } else {
        clearInterval(interval); // Clear the interval

        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.car').css("left", "-=700px");
            interval = setInterval(showcar, 10); // Re-assign the interval
        }, 5000);
    }
};

interval = setInterval(showcar, 10); // Initialize
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the interval in a function and call that function

```
var showcar;

function myInterval() {
    showcar = setInterval(function () {
        ...
        if (...) {
            ...
        } else {
            clearInterval(showcar);
            setTimeout(function() {
                ...
                myInterval();
            },5000);
        }
    }, 10);
}

myInterval();
```

Comment: in the fiddle is not what i suggest

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you want the car to keep returning to its original position and going to the right again you don't need to `clearInterval()`, you just set left to `0px` like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var showcar;
    showcar = setInterval(function () {
        var difference = $(".car").position().left
        if (difference < 750)
        {
            $('.car').css("left", "+=2px");
        }
        else
        {
            //clearInterval(showcar);
            $('.car').css("left", "0px");
        }
    }, 10);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tN33v/) ;)

Comment: Check the demo, you just add the "0px" to the css("left",... instead of "-=700px". clearInterval() and call back funtion is not necesary in this case (:

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want the car to return towards the start quickly and continue to loop the animation of it driving to the right.

Here is a tested, working solution, available on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K4Fh6/1/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var showcar;

    function startAnimation() {

        showcar = setInterval(function () {

            console.log(
                'position: ' 
                + $('.car').css("left"));

            var difference = $(".car").position().left;

            if (difference < 750) {
                $('.car').css("left", "+=2px");
            } else {
                $('.car').css("left", "-=700px");

            }
        }, 10);
    }

    startAnimation();

});
```

**I added a console log of the position to help understand what is happening.*